# Javascriptlet for parsing Geolocation information from Azure Maps API HTTP Request

Tags: javascript, json, accessibility, azure-maps, tasker

I am trying to build a button widget with Tasker that, when pressed, speaks the current user's location in format of Street name and number (for visually impaired people).

Among other, I set up an HTTP Request that uses the retrieved user location and makes a Reverse Address search to Azure Maps API:
[https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/reverse/json?api-version=1.0&subscription-key=[subscription-key]&query=%gl_latitude,%gl_longitude](https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/reverse/json?api-version=1.0&subscription-key=%5Bsubscription-key%5D&query=%gl_latitude,%gl_longitude)

This returns the following JSON (defined as http_data within Tasker):

```
{
    "summary": {
        "queryTime": 34,
        "numResults": 1
    },
    "addresses": [
        {
            "address": {
                "buildingNumber": "1433",
                "streetNumber": "1433",
                "routeNumbers": [],
                "street": "Avenue of the Americas",
                "streetName": "Avenue of the Americas",
                "streetNameAndNumber": "1433 Avenue of the Americas",
                "countryCode": "US",
                "countrySubdivision": "NY",
                "countrySecondarySubdivision": "New York",
                "municipality": "New York",
                "postalCode": "10019",
                "municipalitySubdivision": "Manhattan",
                "country": "United States",
                "countryCodeISO3": "USA",
                "freeformAddress": "1433 Avenue of the Americas, New York, NY 10019",
                "boundingBox": {
                    "northEast": "40.765687,-73.976240",
                    "southWest": "40.765012,-73.976714",
                    "entity": "position"
                },
                "extendedPostalCode": "10019-1532",
                "countrySubdivisionName": "New York",
                "countrySubdivisionCode": "NY",
                "localName": "New York"
            },
            "position": "40.765450,-73.976410",
            "id": "IjKZF6illVLFN65JULL_5w"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, what I need is to extract only the value `streetNameAndNumber` from this information for which I used a Javascriplet action but it fails to extract the field.

This extracted information should be identified and defined as variable that I can name in a Say action `(%streetNameAndAddress)` so it speaks it loud for the user.

I tried a few different options of code but all failed as the info doesn't return and identify the field as information. An example:

```
var data = JSON.parse(global('http_data'));
var streetNameAndAddress = data.addresses[0].address.streetNameAndNumber;
```

When executing is like it doesn't define the variable properly and the Say action returns plain `"%streetNameAndAddress"`.

What would the correct code be?

Thank you for your help and apologies for any wrong terminology usage--I have literally zero xp with Coding.

Comment: I recommend you format your answer properly. Use code blocks for js code.

Comment: In case you are using the interactive map control of Azure Maps, there wouldn't be any need for this as it is already integrated with the screen reader for accessibility purposes and leverages a combination of the reverse geocoder and map tiles to describe the map view to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you're trying to build a button widget with Tasker that speaks the current user's location using the Azure Maps API. You're facing an issue with extracting the `streetNameAndNumber` from the JSON response of the Azure Maps API.

Based on the JSON structure you provided and the code snippet you've tried, it seems like your approach is mostly correct. However, if the Say action returns plain `%streetNameAndAddress`, it indicates that the variable might not be set correctly in Tasker.

Here's a revised version of your JavaScript code:

```js
var data = JSON.parse(global('http_data'));
if (data && data.addresses && data.addresses.length > 0) {
    var streetNameAndAddress = data.addresses[0].address.streetNameAndNumber;
    setGlobal('streetNameAndAddress', streetNameAndAddress);
} else {
    setGlobal('streetNameAndAddress', 'Location not found');
}
```

In this code, I'm first checking if `data`, `data.addresses`, and `data.addresses[0]` are valid before trying to access `streetNameAndNumber`. This is to prevent any potential errors if the data structure is not as expected. Then, I'm using `setGlobal` to set the Tasker global variable `%streetNameAndAddress`.

Please ensure that:

1. The `http_data` variable in Tasker correctly contains the JSON response from the Azure Maps API.
2. The `setGlobal` function is correctly used to set a global variable in Tasker. Replace `setGlobal` with the appropriate method if it differs in your version of Tasker.

If you're still facing issues, double-check the JSON response structure to ensure it matches the path you're using to access `streetNameAndNumber`. Also, make sure that the Tasker JavaScriptlet environment correctly interprets and executes the JavaScript code.

I hope this helps you in getting the desired functionality working. If you have any further questions or run into more issues, feel free to ask!

Comment: @ORDIsBack Highly recommend using the debugger to step through your code.. You can check if the variable states and data types are correct when the code is executed. This is one thing that has helped me resolve many tough issues. If you have any issues, please check YouTube for tutorials.. `debugger` is a much faster way to resolve most issues than `console.log.` You can add a `debugger;` directive in your file, and on the browser, it will start the debugger, and you can step through.

Comment: Thank you @Sarthak Dwivedi. I had to modify the code from `var data = JSON.parse(global('http_data'));` to `var data = JSON.parse(http_data);`. I guess it's because in Tasker’s JavaScript interface, global variables are directly accessible without needing to use the global() function. So, you can directly use `http_data` instead of `global('http_data')`. Thanks for your help throughout.